# Reference Request: Books on Dynamical Systems and Matrix Theory

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I was wondering if there is a good text out there on matrix theory applied to dynamical systems? Often in my researcher, papers will use matrix theory to prove the stability of equilibria or other useful properties, for example, different papers use Perron–Frobenius theorem, Metzler matrix or Hurwitz matrix. I was just wondering if there is a good reference book out for this type of material? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: When I was an undergraduate (late 1970s) a well known advanced undergraduate level text was [**Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123495504) by Hirsch/Smale. A [third edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123820103) exists, but I remember reading somewhere (in fact, I think I actually said this myself somewhere, but I can't find it now) that some stuff was omitted (possibly some of the more extensive aspects of linear algebra?) after the first edition.